# Progress Bar in Play Store like Horizontal CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have followed [this tutorial](http://sourceandroid365.com/horizontal-recyclerview-vertical-recyclerview-google-play-store/) to get a similar UI to google play store i.e a horizontal recyclerview inside a vertical recyclerview.

But, while loading data for each card inside every section, How should I display the progress bar?

Also, if network call is failing then how should I handle the failure? What UI should be displayed in this case so that it sticks to material design guidelines?

Even when I disconnect my phone from Internet, I see playstore app loading text data at least for few of the cards. I have never seen any progress bar in play store app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is network library you are using?

Comment: No external library. HttpUrlConnection only.In one of the case I am querying for Youtube search api using their inbuilt api library.